# Choosing div placement using append in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function moveFront(el){
    var me = $('#'+el.closest('div').attr('id'));
    var parent = me.parent();
    parent.find('div:first').prepend(me);
    //?
}
</script>
<div class="comments">
<div id="105">
    105
    <p>...</p>
    <form>...</form>

    <div id="116">
        116
    </div>
    <div id="106">
        106
    </div>
    <div id="109">
        109
        <button onclick="moveFront($(this));"></button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

1. I would like to append a new `div` element in the element with the ID of 105, however, I don't want it at the end or the start.  It should be before the other `div` elements.
2. If a button was used, as demonstrated in the `div` element with the ID of 109, how would I move it as the first `div` element with the ID of 105?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `before` method:

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('#105 div:first').before('<div id="115"></div>')
$('#109').appendTo($('#105 div:first'))
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtPQZ/7/)

Note that IDs must be *unique* and if the doctype of the page is not HTML5, IDs must begin with a letter.

---

If you want to move the button's div parent to the first div you can try:

```
function moveFront(el){
     el.closest('div').prependTo($('#105 div:first'))
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtPQZ/12/)

Comment: sry, it's div #109 (not the button), that I want to move, see the edited `<script>`

Comment: thx @undefined it's on the right way http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/ZtPQZ/14/ can u tell me when I get an error when pressing the #109's button more than once

Comment: @cyril You can remove the onclick attribute and try this http://jsfiddle.net/ZtPQZ/15/ I have used the `one` method, this should work as you want.

Comment: @cyril `one` handler is executed only once.

Comment: k but at the end, each div have this moveToFront button, so the button can be pressed multiple times, thx

Comment: ahhh sry, actually how to make it work if initially there is still no div in #105 actually I need something more general than http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/ZtPQZ/17/ because I can have more complex elements inside them (not sure the form is the last one)

Comment: @cyril what is the problem cyril? can you elaborate on that? `$('#105').children().last().after()?`, `$('#105').append()`?

Comment: inserting before the first div if any, at the end else

Comment: @cyril Wasn't `$('#105 div:first').before()` helpful?

Comment: this is not working as expected see http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/ZtPQZ/18/ I should have 105 > 115 > 117, 116  instead there are 2 116's// sry right form is matched twice, I'll use closest

Comment: @cyril You are inserting form elements, and after inserting them, there are more than one form in your div tag. try this http://jsfiddle.net/ZtPQZ/19/

Comment: it's ok sorry I'm doing things like this http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/ZtPQZ/20/ thanks bye

Answer (score 0):

ID's should begin with a letter, and they should be unique, you are using `#109` twice ?

```
$('#105').find('div:first') //find the first div
         .before($('<div>New div before div</div>')) //insert element before it
         .end() //start over
         .prepend($('#109')); // prepend the #109 element to #105
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p92An/1/)

Comment: sry edited, ok seems find('div:first') was what I needed, also it's not the button that I want to move but the div containing the button (109)

Comment: @cyril - I see, edited the code to move the entire #109 element, not just the button.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : when I wrote my original answer - I thought the "move front" should move one up. 
I modified the answer to match requirements which is "move to be first"

The points should still belong to "undefined" as he/she answered first. I just couldn't leave my answer like this :)

Here is a full [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnpSt/10/) to the code I will describe below
For the first problem, I would wrap the other divs with another div for example

```
<div class="numbers">
     <div id="195">
     195
     </div>
     .... 
</div>
```

and then use [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) something like  (pseudo code)
and use it like so `$('.numbers').prepend($('<div/>).text('this is a new div'))`

same method to move a div with button to be first:

here is my HTML example :

```
<div id="105">
    105
    <input/>
    <button class="add-this">Add This</button>
    <div class="numbers">
        <div id="116">
            116
        </div>
        <div id="109">
            109
        </div>
        <div id="109">
            109
            <button class="move-front"> Move Front</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my JavaScript example

```
$(function(){    
    $("button.add-this").click(function(){
    var $val = $("input").val();
    $(".numbers").prepend($("<div/>").attr("id",$val).text($val))

    });

$(".numbers").on({
    click:function(){

       var $divToMove = $(this).parent();
       var $currentIndex = $(".numbers div").index($divToMove);

        $divToMove.remove();
        $(".numbers").prepend($divToMove);
    }
}, "button.move-front");

});
```

please let me know if more explanations are required.